# application_start event called multiple times in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application ,I am updating my web.config at runtime through application_start event.So, ideally it should be done only when the application is started.BUT in MY mvc application the application_start event of global.asax is being called multiple times , even when i have not restarted the application.

Its being repetadly called when i am calling different actions , so the webconfig is repetedly updating & making my application very very slow.

Can you please let me know , what's the reason & how to handle this .

Thanks in advance
Aayushi

Answer (score 4):

Everytime you change something in your web.config.  That will refresh your application, therefore application_start is also called everytime you open your site.  When web.config is changed, your application restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which elements in your web.config you are updating. If these are custom elements maybe you can put these things in a separate config file (xml file) and update that file.

Answer (score 1):

You application will be restarted once web.config is modified.

It doesn't make any sense changing web configuration file in application_start. Moving changeable part into a separate file

Comment: It makes perfect sense if you want your configuration to be dynamic and based off of the environment the application is launched to. What if I want to publish my application to a test environment without using ant or maven... and then I forget to change my connection string to the test database. If there is a better way I would like to know myself.

Comment: you don't use ant and maven, and you forget to change connection string.  good for you.

Comment: Actually I found my answer here, http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/new-features-in-webactivator-13.html.   preapplicationstartmethod.  Is perfect to use in this instance to modify the configuration file used by web.config before application start is even hit.